# sed: how do I change the value of the last column in a file?

Tags: sed

I have a file that looks like this:

```
fid1 iid1 0 0 1 1
fid2 iid2 0 0 2 -9
fid3 iid3 0 0 1 1
.
.
```

How do I change all values in the last column to 2 using sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ sed 's/\S*$/2/' yourfile
```

`\S` is for non-whitespace, `$` is for the end of line.

Another solution

```
$ sed 's/\S\+$/2/' yourfile
```

(In `sed`, `+` must be escaped)

Answer (score -2):

cat test* | sed 's/(..)(..)(.*)/\1/\2/\3/'

07/23/2013,0622005,02022001
10/02/2004,09142000,03032004
11/23/2008,1252002,06122005

Comment: Can you explain this answer a little bit? What do the different arguments do, what is the regex doing, etc. Also, check your formatting before you post your answers. I don't think you intended to have such a long string of numbers, and I don't think your regex is looking correct (even if it was entered correctly, due to markup).